# DJango QuerySet filter query using a model attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say I have a model `Example`

```
class Example
   start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
   duration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And a QuerySet class

```
class ExampleQuerySet
    def live_objects():
        self.active().filter(start_time__gte=get_minutes_before(get_utc_now(),5), start_time__lte=get_minutes_after(get_utc_now(), self.duration))
```

The objective of the `live_objects()` method is to return those objects which have their current time > start time and current time < start time + duration of the object

But this above query is failing with the error that `self object doesn't have duration attribute`

How do I go about writing a query where I can filter out objects that are currently live ?

Comment: Is the ExampleQuerySet class inherited by your Example model?

Comment: yes, it is inherited